# How to use inheritance in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

Respected All:
 I want to use the feature of reusability of the Django templates

As i wrote in **base.html**

```
<title>{% block title %}{% trans 'Main Page title' %}{% endblock %}</title>
```

And my **otherfile.html** is this

```
{% block title %}Other file Title{% endblock %}
```

I want to Set the title without useing  tags in otherfile.html is it possible?

Comment: oki, what's the problem that your'e currently facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **otherfile.html** will have this template tag at the top `{% extends "base.html" %}`
After that you can use `% block title %}Other file Title{% endblock %}` in otherfile.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/#templates